# ng-href to open page from json not working in app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this issue, work when I opened on web browser but not on my android smartphone.

```
<ion-list>  
  <ion-item class="list" >
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-href="{{x.Adress}}" ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'" >
      <img ng-src="{{x.Image}}">
      <h2>{{x.Name}}</h2>
      <p>{{x.Local}}</p>
      <p>{{x.Descri}}</p>
    </a>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

```html
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("patrocinadores.json")
      .success(function (response) 
      {
       $scope.names = response;
      });
})
```

Comment: do you have an error ?

Comment: Please add the controller too. How `names` looks like?

Comment: on my browser returns 0 errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try write Address without interpolation:
For example:

And verify your property name.

Or you can try (not fancy):

```
<ion-list>  
    <ion-item class="list" >
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="Open(x.Adress)" ng-repeat="x in names|orderBy:'Name'" >
  <img ng-src="{{x.Image}}">
  <h2>{{x.Name}}</h2>
  <p>{{x.Local}}</p>
  <p>{{x.Descri}}</p>
</a>
```

in your controller:

```
$scope.Open = function(url){
    window.open(url, '_system');
};
```

Don't forget in your "a" tag you need set target attr to "system" to load or open your link with default system browser instead of embebed ionic view.

I hope this can help you.